# Java equivalent of python's String lstrip()?

Tags: java, string, trim

I'd like to remove the leading whitespace in a string, but without removing the trailing whitespace - so trim() won't work.  In python I use lstrip(), but I'm not sure if there's an equivalent in Java.

As an example

```
"    foobar    "
```

should become

```
"foobar    "
```

I'd also like to avoid using Regex if at all possible.

Is there a built in function in Java, or do I have to go about creating my own method to do this?  (and what's the shortest way I could achieve that)

Comment: May I ask why not regex? krock's answer looks like the shortest way to do this. And it's perfectly readable, fast and does not require any extra libraries.

Comment: @tulskiy I consider using StringUtils for this task to be more readable and better convey the intent of the action.

Comment: @Christian Semaru: I understand that commons lang is a great library, but adding the whole library to a project because of one simple task is an overkill.

Comment: @tulskiy: Except that you usually end up using `StringUtils` for more than a single task. Using it is a kind of default for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this in a regular expression:

```
"    foobar    ".replaceAll("^\\s+", "");
```

Comment: It's funny how the one answer containing regex got accepted when it was stated that regex should be avoided. Personally I would use regex as well instead of a library--except that library is already part of the project.

Answer (score 10):

You could use the `StringUtils` class of [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) which has a `stripStart()` method (and many many more).

Answer (score 2):

[Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) has `CharMatcher.WHITESPACE.trimLeadingFrom(string)`.  This by itself is not that different from other utility libraries' versions of the same thing, but once you're familiar with `CharMatcher` there is a tremendous breadth of text processing operations you'll know how to perform in a consistent, readable, performant manner.

Answer (score 1):

Since Java11 you can use `.stripLeading()` on a String to remove leading white-spaces and `.stripTrailing()` to remove trailing white-spaces.

The documentation for this can be found here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#stripLeading()

Example:

```java
String s = "    Hello there.    ";
s.stripLeading();    // "Hello there.    "
s.stripTrainling();  // "    Hello there."
s.strip();           // "Hello there."
```

Answer (score 0):

[org.springframework.util.StringUtils.trimLeadingWhitespace(String)](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/springframework/spring/1.2.9/spring-1.2.9-javadoc.jar!/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html#trimLeadingWhitespace(java.lang.String))

Comment: The Javadocs say *"Miscellaneous string utility methods. Mainly for internal use within the framework; consider Jakarta's Commons Lang for a more comprehensive suite of string utilities."*